# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being called in very rare cases or not being called most time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So once again the famous topic. I have to say that I had read all the similar topics here and also googled it. But nothing helps.
My app's structure is as follows:
`RootController` is `TabController`, then every tab has its own `NavigationController` with the `ViewController` inside. And inside the ViewController I placed a `UITableView`. All designed in IB. `DataSource` and `Delegate` are connected properly. `TableView` uses custom `TableCell` but also I had tried the standard `TableCell`. Also there is a `UISegmentedControl` to change the `DataSource` array
What I checked and double checked (in short everything I had found in similar topics):

- my `ViewController` does declare and implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` (or It wont be possible to connect corresponding properties in IB)
- `DataSource` and `Delegate` properties are connected properly in IB. Also it is duplicated in code by `setDelegate:self` and `setDataSource:self`.
- my custom `TableCell` has marked User Interaction Enabled
- my custom `TableCell` contains 2 labels and one image all with no User Interaction Enabled mark
- it calls `[tableView reloadData]`
- tried to `[tableView becomeFirstResponder]`
- TableView has options like Single cell choosing, Allow User Interaction, Allow cell selection while editing etc. marked
- there is no typo in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like DEselect or something. Futhermore the `TableView`'s delegate methods were copypasted from working app with changing the code inside methods. I mean there couldn't be any typos in method's names/declaring.
- the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method contains only one code line and it is `NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");`
- `XCode` was restarted several times
- made the `clean all targets`
- not using the `ARC` in the project
- there are no heavy operations or any other operations running while displaying the table

The `TableView` by itself works fine in meaning of filling with data and displaying it. But if I tap the cell it highlights with blue and it looks like that it freezes the choice. From the moment It highlighted one cell any other cell couldn't be highlighted and highlighted cell couldn't be unselected. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called. But if try to tap the cells many many times with dragging the table then sometimes the method does call. Like in being called in very rare cases and if there are not more than 3 records in a table. It is a very strange issue and I cant fight it. I feel like TableView receives the tap but somehow cant handle it.
the ViewController:

```
@interface SecondTabVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> 
{

    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * sgmTopMenu; //has 3 segments

    NSArray * arrHrefLinks;
    NSArray * arrImgLinks;

    IBOutlet UIImageView * imgFiles;

    int selectedSegmentIndex;
    IBOutlet UITableView* tblLinks;

}

@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * sgmTopMenu;

@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * imgFiles;

@property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray * arrHrefLinks;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray * arrImgLinks;

@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tblLinks;


-(IBAction)onTopMenuTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation:

```
    // called when UIsegment's Value changed, linked in IB
    -(IBAction)onTopMenuTap:(id)sender
    {

        selectedSegmentIndex = ((UISegmentedControl*)sender).selectedSegmentIndex;

        NSLog(@"onTopMenuTap: %i",selectedSegmentIndex);

        switch (selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: 
            case 1: 
                tblLinks.hidden = NO;
                tblLinks.delegate = self;
                tblLinks.dataSource = self;
                tblLinks.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                tblLinks.allowsSelection=YES;
                tblLinks.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
                [tblLinks reloadData];
                [tblLinks becomeFirstResponder];
                break;
            case 2: // settings
                tblLinks.hidden = YES;
    //          tblLinks.delegate = nil;
    //          tblLinks.dataSource = nil;
                break;
        }

    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        int numberOfRowsInSection=0;
        switch (selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: 
                numberOfRowsInSection = arrHrefLinks.count;
                break;
            case 1: 
                numberOfRowsInSection = arrImgLinks.count;
                break;
        }
        return numberOfRowsInSection;
    }

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LinkCell *cell= (LinkCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LINK_CELL_ID];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 loadNibNamed:LINK_CELL_ID
                 owner:self 
                 options:nil] lastObject];

    // Setting up the cell...
    HTMLNode * node = nil;
    NSString * header = nil;
    switch (selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: 
            node = [arrHrefLinks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            header = [node getAttributeNamed:@"title"];
            if (!header || header.length==0)
                header = [node contents];
            if (!header || header.length==0)
                header = [node allContents];
            if (!header || header.length==0)
                [node getAttributeNamed:@"name"];
            cell.lblName.text = header;
            //cell.textLabel.text = header;
            cell.lblUrl.text = [node getAttributeNamed:@"href"];
            break;
        case 1: 
            node = [arrImgLinks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            header = [node getAttributeNamed:@"title"];
            if (!header || header.length==0)
                [node getAttributeNamed:@"name"];
            if (!header || header.length==0)
                header = [node contents];
            if (!header || header.length==0)
                header = [node allContents];
            cell.lblName.text = header;
            //cell.textLabel.text = [header copy];
            cell.lblName.text = [node getAttributeNamed:@"name"];
            //cell.lblUrl.text = [node getAttributeNamed:@"src"];

            break;
    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
}
```

Comment: Well the same comment show us some code!! didSelectRowAtIndexpath

Comment: Posting relevant code and telling issue in two or more sentence is much better than 1000 lines of explanation. Could you please post the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wont found any issue in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method cuz its empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found the issue's source. It is PSWebView. It was placed at 1st tab's view but seems like it intercepts all the taps in any other controllers. Getting rid of it solves my issue. BTW PSWebView doesn't use gestures so the issue is not about gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code to deselect the row ,Otherwise it will remain selected.And I think it is the reason for your problem.So do this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: if didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called what is the point of placing something inside it?

Comment: I said it was called in very rare cases and if I very often tap the cell. It wasn't the issue anyway. More over I did implement this method with only NSLog inside - did you noticed that? Anyway if code works correctly there is no need to call deselectRowAtIndexPath.